# How to properly process base64 to stored server image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on an add-item page for a basic webshop, the shop owner can add item images via drag/drop or browsing directly. When images are selected i'm storing the base64 in an array. I'm now not too sure how best to deal with sending/storing of these item images for proper use. After giving Google a bit of love i'm thinking the image data could be sent as base64 and saved back to an image via something like `file_put_contents('/item-images/randomNumber.jpg', base64_decode($base64));` then adding the item's image paths to its database data for later retrieval. Below is an untested example of how i currently imagine sending the image data, is something like this right?

```
$("#addItem").click(function() {
    var imgData = "";
    $.each(previewImagesArray, function(index, value) {
        imgData += previewImagesArray[index].value;
    });
    $.post
    (
        "/pages/add-item.php",
        "name="+$("#add-item-name").val()+
        "&price="+$("#add-item-price").val()+
        "&desc="+$("#add-item-desc").val()+
        "&category="+$("#add-item-category :selected").text()+
        "&images="+imgData
    );
    return false;
});
```

Really appreciate any help, i'm relatively new to web development.

Comment: What you propose is perfectly sound, except for "randomNumber.jpg" as one random number may equal another. A good method of creating a unique file name while also preventing duplicates of images is to use the md5 hash of the *contents* of the file as the file name. The md5 hash is incredibly unlikely to be the same as that of another image.

Comment: Ok super, i just wasn't sure posting potentially enormous chunks of data via $.post() like this was correct.

Comment: I didn't answer the question on that point. You may want to ask that particular question more specifically to get a proper answer. See how you go though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are doing, so do I essentially: get the base64 from the browser, then post back, and store.  A few comments...

First, HTML POST has no mandatory size limitation, but practically your backend will limit the size of posted data.  (eg, 2M `max_post_size` in PHP.)  Since you are sending base64, you are significantly reducing the effective payload you can send. That is, if every one byte of image equals three bytes of base64, you will get far less image transfered per byte of network.  Either send multiple posts or increase your post size to fit your needs.

Second, as @popnoodles mentioned, using a `randomNumber` will likely not be sufficient in the long term.  Use either a database primary key or the `tempnam` family of functions to generate a unique identifier.  I disagree with @popnoodleson implementation, however: it's quite possible to upload the same file b/w two different people.  For example, my c2013 Winter Bash avatar on SO was taken from an online internet library.  Someone else could use that same icon.  We would collide, so the MD5 is not sufficient in general, but in your use case could be.

Finally, you probably will want to base64 decode, but give some thought to whether you need it.  You can use a data/url and inline the base64 image data.  This has the same network issue as before: significantly more transfer is required to send it.  But, a data URL works very well for lots of very small images (eg avatars) or pages that will be cached for a very long time (esp if your users have reasonable data connections).  Summary: consider the use case before presuming you need to base64 decode.